# My WordPress site is hyphenating search terms

Tags: wordpress, http, get

I'm working on a WordPress site whose search is not working.  If I try to search for "health data", the search term becomes "health-data" which is unlikely to find anything.  I'm using search.php and searchform.php as per WordPress documentation.  As a side note, if I put a breakpoint in the first line of /index.php, there is no $_GET object at all.

However, if I create a test.html page at https://sitename/test.html with that exact same form html in it, the search term is "health data" which finds several results.

I've been racking my brain trying to find out what may be causing this.  I've turned off most of the plugins and have commented-out most of the functions.php file but it's still hyphenating the search term on the "normal" search page.

If anyone seeing this has any ideas I'm all open.

Comment: If this is likely to be a *configuration* problem, rather than a *code* problem, you may find that asking at https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/ and following their guidelines for what to include, and what tags to use, might get you better help.